# creating custom errors with Javascript ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm reading the following snippet from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)'s web docs on how to extend the builtin Error in Javascript. I'm using ES5 because I've had issues getting it to work with ES6 syntax.

What I don't understand is: is `"Code Chunk C"` necessary?

`"Code Chunk B"` sets the prototype of CustomError to be an object whose (1) prototype will be `Error.prototype` and (2) will have a property named `constructor` with a value of `Error`.

In the following code chunk (`"Code Chunk C"`), `Object.setPrototypeOf`, from my understanding, will set the prototype of `CustomError` to be `Error`. This is confusing, didn't we just set the prototype to be `Error.prototype`? I tested the code both with and without this code chunk, and in both cases, the resulting was true:

`const error = CustomError()`

`error.__proto__ === BaseError.prototype // True`

`error.__proto__.__proto__ === Error.prototype // True`

This is not what I expected because I didn't expect `Error.prototype` to be the same as `Error`.

Can someone answer the following:

1) Is the `"Code Chunk C"` necessary if `"Code Chunk B"` is run first?
2) How is `"Code Chunk B"` and `"Code Chunk C"` doing the same thing given my confusion explained previously?

Thanks in advance!

```js
// Start: Code Chunk A
function CustomError(foo, message, fileName, lineNumber) {
  var instance = new Error(message, fileName, lineNumber);
  instance.foo = foo;
  Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
  if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
    Error.captureStackTrace(instance, CustomError);
  }
  return instance;
}
// End: Code Chunk A

// Start: Code Chunk B
CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    value: Error,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
});
// End: Code Chunk B

// Start: Code Chunk C
// Is the following necessary?
if (Object.setPrototypeOf){
  Object.setPrototypeOf(CustomError, Error);
} else {
  CustomError.__proto__ = Error;
}
// End: Code Chunk C
```

Comment: What is the point of overwriting `CustomError.prototype`?